# Find coordinates of a substring in UILabel

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel

I have a string coming from server which I am displaying on UILabel. It is within that string, I am identifying some particular substring. I want to place a button on that substring(button will be a subview of UILabel). For this I require substring coordinates. I went through [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/1278483#file_ui_label%2Bfix.m) but I am not able to understand it.

Suppose my complete string is **abc, 567-324-6554, New York**. I want **567-324-6554** to be displayed on button, for which I need its coordinates. How can I use above link to find coordinates of substring?

Comment: Can't you achieve the same using length of first string, instead of going for coordinate.

Comment: I need x and y for displaying the button on substring.

Comment: You can calculate those based on label's x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be you can calculate using-

```
CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:myFont 
                       constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                           lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Now New position-

```
x = self.myLabel.frame.origin.x + stringSize.width
```

and for y similarly you need to have code with consideration of x.

Comment: This could be useful. But the text is sometimes coming in single line and sometimes in multiple lines.

Comment: the text in your label after which you wish to have button is your string. And regarding your first question i already wrote that you need to consider for y more because of multiple line text.

Comment: And what will be maximumSize?

Comment: size of total text inside that label(including button text as well.)